# Chrome & IE: onpaste event not firing?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, paste

I (like many others) am trying to sanitise text that I'm pasting into a contentEditable iframe. I'm not using jQuery (it's a very ancient code base) and the handler is attached like so:

```
if (isIE) {
  iframe.attachEvent("onpaste",handler);
}
else {
  iframe.addEventListener("paste",handler,true);
}
```

This works in Firefox and Opera, but in IE 10 and the latest version of Chrome (29.0.1547.62), the handler is never called; I put a breakpoint at the first line of the handler, but when paste I some text it doesn't reach the breakpoint and the pasted text just appears (unsanitised). I tried using IE10 in IE 9 mode and it makes no difference. Other handlers seem to be called as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

TIA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the iframe is loaded with a blank page and then programmatically filled with content. The event listener was being added prior to rewriting the iframe document, and this was the cause of the problem. The listener needs to be added *after* the iframe content has been rewritten. Here's a test case:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Paste test&</title>
<script>
  function handler() {
    alert("Paste");
  }

  function register(iframe) {
    //
    //  IE10 requires addEventListener to be used, so this
    //  is preferable to doing browser detection...
    //
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      iframe.addEventListener("paste",handler,true);
    }
    else {
      iframe.attachEvent("onpaste",handler);
      }
  }

  function test() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("frm").contentWindow;
    try {
      var doc = iframe.document;
      if (!doc) {
        setTimeout(test,50);
        return;
      }
//      register(iframe);   // this won't work!
      doc.open();
      doc.write("<html><body>Paste text here: []</body></html>");
      doc.close();
      doc.body.contentEditable = true;
      register(iframe);     // this works!
    }
    catch (e) {
      setTimeout(test,50);
      return;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test()">
Here is the iframe:
<p>
<iframe id="frm" src="blank.html" width="400" height="200"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Historical note: the onpaste code was originally part of a ^V handler dating back presumably to days before onpaste was widely supported, and adding a keypress/keydown handler before messing with the iframe worked. Having thought about it, it seems likely that what happened to me was that the onpaste handler cannot be set until the iframe is content-editable (at which point pasting is possible).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `iframe` refers to the `iframe` element on the main page (though in this case I couldn't get this work even in FF23). You could use a cross-browser way to refer the `window` object within the `iframe` instead:

HTML:

```
<iframe name="iframe" ...></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var iframe = window.frames['iframe'];
if (window.addEventListener) {
  iframe.addEventListener('paste', handler);
}
else {
  iframe.attachEvent('onpaste', handler);
}
```

Notice also the feature detection instead of browser detection.

What comes to Chrome, I'm not sure, I couldn't test  the code locally, since looks like `-allow-access-to-files` doesn't work in Chrome29.

Comment: iframe is a variable referencing the content window of the iframe element, so that I can catch paste events inside the iframe content window rather than for the entire page. (I don't see what -allow-access-to-files has to do with anything, though!)

Comment: Are you sure? If it really is, this works in IE10, and the error is probably caused by `handler()`. The meaning of the  `-allow-access-to-files` you can find out by reading my answer again ; ).

Comment: Testing for window.addEventListener is probably better style, but it makes no difference to the outcome.

Comment: Well, the name "-allow-access-to-files" suggests that Chrome would want to access the local file system, but what does that have to do with pasting? Meanwhile stripping the handler down to { alert("foo"); } means that I get an alert in FF but not Chrome or IE10. So the handler isn't being called, but there's nothing on the error console to suggest that anything bad happened when installing it.

Comment: The actual problem is that my handler is only being called if I use Firefox or Opera!

Comment: A stripped-down example works in IE10 (but still not in Chrome), so I'm continuing my investigations... Thanks for the advice so far.

Comment: I just found the answer... the iframe is loaded with a blank page and then programmatically filled with content. The event listener was being added prior to rewriting the iframe document, and this seems not to work in IE or Chrome (but does in Firefox!). Adding the listener _after_ rewriting the iframe works. Duh. (Oh, and testing for window.addEventListener turns out to be essential in IE10. Thanks for pointing this out.)